# cross platform api or bin file to validate daylight savings time in a system

Tags: linux, datetime, timezone, dst

I want to get the status of daylight savings time in cross platforms as in the command `timedatectl` as **active/not active**. Since I am trying it with cross platforms I don't want to use timedatectl.

`So my questions are:`

1. When I use **timedatectl status** command in my system, it is not showing the DST Status. I don't know why. Can anybody explain this?

** **My System output** **

```
$ timedatectl status
Local time: Tue 2021-06-29 16:26:16 IST
           Universal time: Tue 2021-06-29 10:56:16 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2021-06-29 10:56:16    
                Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)  
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: active                     
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

It is not showing `DST active : a (or) n/a` status. I want know why?

2. Is there any default API or bin files similar to **timedatectl** to do the job of validating the DST is active/not status in the system (cross platforms)?

Comment: I deleted the C tag as I don't see how this relates to C. Further, I don't think this belongs at stackoverflow at all. Perhaps superuser is a better site!?

Comment: Actually I need API in C that's why I included C tag. I'll try it with superuser. Thankyou